# bulding association with has_many :through in multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Please help to understand how to do `@project.payments` having this tree:

```
Project
   |__Stages
         |__Costs
              |__Payments
```

project.rb

```
 has_many :stages
 has_many :costs, :through => stages
```

stage.rb

```
belongs_to :project
has_many :costs
has_many :payments :through => costs
```

cost.rb

```
belongs_to :stage
has_many :payments
```

payment.rb

```
belongs_to :cost
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: As this is a nested has_many :through relationship, it'll only work in Rails 3.1+ (RC4 of 3.1 is out)

project.rb

```
has_many :payments, :through => costs
```

Comment: Oh, this is great, thanks! I'll update my app! I'm just curious, is there a way to do it in Rails 3.0 somehow?

Comment: Yes, there is. Check out my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318712/rails-models-relationships/6318745#6318745