# Multiple has_many/joins or create new relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

What is the best way for next case.
User belongs to family (by family_id), family (by building_id) belongs to building, building (by street_id) belongs to street... etc.

street.users is common and frequent action.

What is the rails way, – build own active record method based on multiple 'joins' or just add 'street_id' and has_many to the User model?

Answer (score 3):

`has_many :users, through: :families` should work in `Street` model. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438985/bulding-association-with-has-many-through-in-multiple-models) for details.